# Select last chars of string until whitespace in Python

Tags: python, string

Is there any efficient way to select the last characters of a string until there's a whitespace in Python?

For example I have the following string:

```
str = 'Hello my name is John'
```

I want to return 'John'. But if the str was:

```
str = 'Hello my name is Sally'
```

I want to retrun 'Sally'

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Just split the string on whitespace, and get the last element of the array. Or use `rsplit()` to start splitting from end:

```
>>> st = 'Hello my name is John'
>>> st.rsplit(' ', 1)
['Hello my name is', 'John']
>>> 
>>> st.rsplit(' ', 1)[1]
'John'
```

The 2nd argument specifies the number of `split` to do. Since you just want last element, we just need to split once.

As specified in comments, you can just pass `None` as 1st argument, in which case the default delimiter which is whitespace will be used:

```
>>> st.rsplit(None, 1)[-1]
'John'
```

Using `-1` as index is safe, in case there is no whitespace in your string.

Comment: You can use `None` instead of `' '`.

Comment: Explicit is better than implicit!  I believe `' '` is definitely the only advisable way to `rsplit` the string.

Comment: @hexparrot Except that `None` splits at any whitespace (space, \t, \n...) character, while `' '` only at spaces. The question was actually whitespaces, so None is a more accurate answer...

Answer (score 3):

It really depends what you mean by efficient, but the simplest (efficient use of programmer time) way I can think of is:

```
str.split()[-1]
```

This fails for empty strings, so you'll want to check that.

Answer (score 2):

I think this is what you want:

`str[str.rfind(' ')+1:]`

this creates a substring from `str` starting at the character after the right-most-found-space, and up until the last character.

This works for all strings - empty or otherwise (unless it's not a string object, e.g. a None object would throw an error)

Comment: For left-most space use `str[:str.find(' ')]`.